# SharePoint 2013 immediate alerts randomly not sent

Tags: 2013, alert

I have a random issue wiht Immediate alerts on SharePoint 2013. On a library , a user has created an immediate alert on document creation and modification.

The issue is that sometimes the user receives an email on a document creation and sometimes not.

Other users having created also an alert on the same library receive the alert on the same document creation and some others not

On the next document creation the list of users who do not receive notification will change and so on

After some primary investivations, the issue seems to be in SharePoint and not in the mail infrastructure (Exchange).

Has someone already had this kind of issue on SharePoint 2013 (alerts randomly not sent)
Is there a way in SharePoint to see the alerts sent (mail and hour) ?, maybe somewhere in content database ?

thanks for your help !

Comment: I'd doublecheck the smtp server in the outgoing email settings to make sure the smtp server listed accepts anonymous emails.

Comment: thanks for your response. the alerts are most of the time correctly sent. i think that the smtp server is ok as well as the SharePoint outgoing email configuration

Comment: are the alerts working always for some users, but not at all for others? Or sometimes one user will get an alert and other times the same user will not? If the problem is intermittent, usually it's an email infrastructure problem

Answer (score 0):

Are the alerts working always for some users, but not at all for others? Or sometimes one user will get an alert and other times the same user will not?

If the problem is intermittent, usually it's an email infrastructure problem. SharePoint determines who should and who should not get emails before the `SPUtility.SendEmail()` method fires, and then sends that email through the SMTP server. It's up to the SMTP server and underlying email servers to determine if the mail is sent properly.

Check out this post: http://sharepointalert.info/2009/11/troubleshooting-sharepoint-email-alerts-check-email-setupinfrastructure/

Comment: sometimes one user will get an alert and other times the same user will not

Comment: I'd sit down with your Exchange or Email infrastructure guy and figure out why it's not sending ALL the time. Check anti-virus, check ports, check firewall, and receive connectors, make sure emails don't have to be authenticated to send, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it did happen to me, on a pool of 80 people there was a succession list almost Always the same of the first person getting it after 1 minute, the second after 3 minutes, the third after 4 minutes, the last person was getting it after 40-50 min and there were some not getting it at all.

It was a sort of bottleneck in Exchange. Maybe an overload. It did happen to me 3 or 4 times in a 2 day span and the problem was in Exchange (granted you checked the alerts were not in the spam).

When it does work it should send all the alerts together, and even if they are 200 or 300 alerts (that was my max number of users) it does send them all together, unless some user have problems in their single inbox.

Answer (score 0):

look in the eventcache table in your sharepoint content database(s).
That's the database with the default name WSS_content.
From SSMS > change focus to WSS_content and query eventcache table
OR
use WSS_content
select * from eventcachce

That will give you a list of the alerts.

Hope that helps